# How do I create Test cases for validation methods in Jestjs

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am new to Jestjs and enzyme framework and I am trying to write test cases for a particular react component and I am little stuck.

```
export class ProductDetailsForm extends Component{

    handleMetaDataDefinition = e => {
    const { value, name } = e.target;
    if (name === "xmlVersion") {
        this.checkSpecialCharacters(value);
    }
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        [name]: value
    }));
    this.props.setProductDetailsFormValue({
        ...this.props.productDetailsForm,
        [name]: value
        });
    };

    checkSpecialCharacters = value => {
        if (!value || value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+$/)) {
            this.setState(() => ({ error: '' }));
        } else {
            this.setState(() => ({
                error: `Special characters and operators such as !@#$%^&*()+{}:;?|\\[]'"= are not allowed`
            }));
        }
    }
    
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <MetaDataDefinition
                    readOnly={false}
                    metaData={this.state}
                    handleMetaDataDefinition={this.handleMetaDataDefinition}
                    validateVersion={this.validateVersion}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I have started with the test case, but I am stuck and unable to proceed how to work on the function handleMetaDataDefinition for full coverage including the function checkSpecialCharacters. Below is the code that I started to write for ProductDetailsForm.test.js

```
let wrapper;
beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(
        <ProductDetailForm />
    );
});

test("should call handleMetaDataDefinition", ()=> {
    wrapper.find('MetaDataDefinition').props('handleMetaDataDefinition');
});
```

I have used some part of my actual code and not the whole code, as I need help in this specific part only to write test case for handleMetaDataDefinition and checkSpecialCharacters methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're two possible option how to write your tests.

1. You can trigger validation from your MetaDataDefinition component and pass there needed data.

```
    test("should call handleMetaDataDefinition", ()=> {
        const component = wrapper.find('MetaDataDefinition');
        fillYourComponentSomehow();
        triggerAnEventSomehow();
        /*For example component.find('button').simulate('click');
        wrapper.update();// We can wait for updating state differently(if needed i'll take a look to doc.)
        expect(wrapper.state()).toBe(stateThatYouExpect);
    });
```

2. Or you can test it as 'black box'

```
    test("should call handleMetaDataDefinition", ()=> {
        const component = wrapper.find('MetaDataDefinition');
        component.props().handleMetaDataDefinition(objectForMethod)
        wrapper.update();
        expect(wrapper.state()).toBe(stateThatYouExpect);
    });
```

If you have HOCs around your component you'll need to find this component by class name
`wrapper.find('ProductDetailsForm')`

**UPDATE**
You can test it like

```
let wrapper;
let setProductDetailsFormValue;
beforeEach(() => {
   setProductDetailsFormValue = jest.fn();
    wrapper = shallow(
        <ProductDetailForm setProductDetailsFormValue={setProductDetailsFormValue} />
    );
});
test("should call handleMetaDataDefinition", ()=> {
        const testObject = { target: {name: 'xmlVersion', value: '!!!123asd!'}, }
        const component = wrapper.find('MetaDataDefinition');
        component.props().handleMetaDataDefinition(testObject)
        wrapper.update();
        expect(wrapper.state().error).toBe('Special characters and operators such as !@#$%^&*()+{}:;?|\\[]'"= are not allowed');
        expect(wrapper.state()[xmlVersion]).toBe('!!!123asd!');
        expect(setProductDetailsFormValue).toBeCalledWith({
             [xmlVersion]: '!!!123asd!',
             ...other fields})
    });
```

Comment: Also you call this.setState few times for each call of 'handleMetaDataDefinition' it's better to avoid such things)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how will I test the line of code 
if (name === "xmlVersion") { this.checkSpecialCharacters(value); }

Comment: I added UPDATE for your question